# Does message ordering in google pub sub honor ack deadline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have set `setAckDeadlineSeconds(5)` when creating subscription, but when message ordering is enabled, the `ackDeadlineSeconds` does not work. The message is not redelivered if time elapsed is over ack deadline. Is this the desired behavior when message ordering is enabled?

I am creating subscription as below:

```java
Subscription request = Subscription.newBuilder()
          .setName(subscriptionName.toString())
          .setTopic(projectTopicName.toString())
          .setEnableMessageOrdering(true)
          .setAckDeadlineSeconds(5)
          .build();
```

Comment: What are you using to subscribe? If you are using the Cloud Pub/Sub client library, it uses its own ack deadline independent of what is configured in the subscription.

Comment: I am using java client library to subscribe.. and have this set in subscriber.. .setMaxAckExtensionPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).

Comment: Can you show how do you use this subscription, and how do you connect to it?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere here is an example project. https://github.com/puneetkhanal/pubsub-demo/blob/a5e3a9ca9fe70305c0e2ebbf81b4b67bdcba1b00/src/main/java/demo/OrderedMessageRedelivery.java#L23. In the example, i don't ack or nack message 1 and I am expecting it to be redelivered.

Comment: And the message is never redelivered? If it is, after how many time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ack deadlines should be respected when messasge ordering is enabled. One thing to note is that the client libraries manage ack extension and therefore do not use the ack deadline set on subscription creation. They default to extending ack deadlines for one hour. You mention that you call `setMaxAckExtensionPeriod`, though you only do that when in [emulator mode in `getSubscriber`](https://github.com/puneetkhanal/pubsub-demo/blob/a5e3a9ca9fe70305c0e2ebbf81b4b67bdcba1b00/src/main/java/demo/PubSubUtils.java#L163-L169) not  [`createSubscriber`](https://github.com/puneetkhanal/pubsub-demo/blob/a5e3a9ca9fe70305c0e2ebbf81b4b67bdcba1b00/src/main/java/demo/PubSubUtils.java#L49-L59), the latter of which is [the method you are calling](https://github.com/puneetkhanal/pubsub-demo/blob/a5e3a9ca9fe70305c0e2ebbf81b4b67bdcba1b00/src/main/java/demo/OrderedMessageRedelivery.java#L40) (though maybe you have since updated the code to set this everywhere).

If after verifying that you are indeed setting the max ack extension you are still not getting message redelivered, it is best to [create a support case](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/createcase). With a case that includes your project and subscription information, support can look at what is happening to those messages that are not getting redelivered.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification. I now understand it. Also, it's working now after updating the test case. I tested exponential backoff as well and it's working.